# query params are missing from the url in angular 6

Tags: routes, angular6

The url entered directly is not showing the query parameters in the url.

i have given my route path as:

```
{ path: 'userdetails/:id', component: userdetailscomponent}
```

And my url is need to work as

```
https://www.(site).com/userdetails?id=5.
```

But the url is working as:

```
https://www.(site).com/userdetails
```

The query params is not showing when the url is directly opened in the browser. The query params are disappearing and the url is going to main route with out query param .How can i get the query param to work and is their any way to get the lost query params?

Comment: Refer this to get a better understanding on 'Route parameters' (https://youtu.be/KefdTtsoKjY)

Comment: Thank you, But here the problem is if the admin directly send the url to the user using sms or email adding their id , so when directly opening the url it is missing with the query params. I am unable to see the query params at all.

Comment: 1. that was not the question you asked and please refer this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

2. when you are sharing a url with or without query parameters, the browser or the email client will not pinpoit that as a query parameter or not. it will act as a basic url. so when you are sharing the url and if it's missing the parameter, i'd recommend you to look into the share function. because the url is a string.

`{{HOST}}/{{BASE}}/events/find/available-venue?startDate=2019-10-10&startTime=06:00&endDate=2019-10-10&endTime=23:00` is a working API and you can share it as it is!

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of approach. [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-query-parameter-example)

Use this way for query parameters

```
{ path: "userdetails", component: UserDetailsComponent}
```

In your typescript file

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

userId;
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.userId = params['id'] || 0;
  });
}
```

In your html file

```
<div *ngIf="userId; else userDetail">
   <h2>User Details for the user with id {{userId}}</h2>
</div>

<ng-template #userDetail>
   User Details Component
</ng-template>
```

How to use this

```
Here sends query param id value as 15
<a [routerLink]="['/userdetails']" [queryParams]="{ id: 15}">User Details 
 with query parameter</a>

Without query parameters 
<a [routerLink]="['/userdetails' ]">User Details</a>
```